# Unity изменение излучения ( Emission ) через код C#

Tags: c#, unity3d

Всем привет. Вопрос собственно вот в чем. Как через С# изменить излучение  ( Emission ).

Пробовал следующим способом, но безрезультатно:

```
MeshRenderer renderer;  
...
public void SetColor (Color col) {

    bool Painted = false;

    Debug.Log ("Change color");

    if (col == Color.green) {
        renderers [0].material.color = new Color32 (60, 100, 70, 255);
        renderers [1].material.color = new Color32 (50, 50, 50, 255);
        renderers [2].material.color = new Color32 (50, 50, 50, 255);
        renderers [3].material.color = new Color32 (50, 150, 50, 255);

        // излучение
        renderers [0].material.SetColor ("_EmissionColor", new Color32 (0, 25, 0, 255));

        renderers [1].material.SetColor ("_EmissionColor", new Color32 (0, 25, 0, 255));

        renderers [2].material.SetColor ("_EmissionColor", new Color32 (0, 25, 0, 255));

        renderers [3].material.SetColor ("_EmissionColor", new Color32 (0, 25, 0, 255));


        Painted = true;

    }
    ...
}
```

Но на деле, излучение не обновляется ... Если через иерархию проверить объект, то при разворачивании информации о шейдере, обновляется излучение ...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У меня обновляется. Где вызывается этот код?

Comment: Обновил пост, по сути дела данная функция дергается с кнопки ...

Comment: renderers  и renderer это опечатка? Это массив ??? покажи весь код

Comment: У меня все работает... не знаю что у тебя.       var  renderers = GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
        renderers.materials[0].SetColor("_EmissionColor", new  Color32(50, 25, 255, 100));
        renderers.materials[1].SetColor("_EmissionColor", new Color32(50, 25, 255, 100));          ....

Comment: Может из-за условия? Проверь оно выполняется?

Comment: Хм ... странно... Не, условие точно выполняется, т.к. цвет меняется renderers [i].material.color = new Color32 (50, 150, 50, 255);

Comment: если не разобрался давай ссылку.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Пример окна настроек из Unity с нужным параметром]

В Unity 2018.2.6f1 эту проблему мне помогло решить использование значения "**Realtime**" в свойстве "**Global Illumination**"

P.S.: C#-код такой же.

```
    MeshRenderer renderer;

    void SetEmissionColor(){

        renderers.materials[0].SetColor("_EmissionColor", new Color(.5F, .3F, .7F, 1F));

    }
```